# Linux shell understanding

Tags: linux, shell

**I am not getting how this script works, What do the following commands mean?**

```
sed -n '/Domain Summary: Message Delivery/,/Domain Summary: Messages Received/p' test_mx1 | grep "yahoo.com"
```

**Below too**

```
sed -n '/Domain Summary: Messages Received/,/Senders by message count/p' test_mx1 | grep "yahoo.com"
```

I am unable to understand these commands.

Answer (score 1):

The script is processing the file `test_mx1`.  The `-n` option for `sed` means 'do not print each line' (which it does normally).

```
'/Domain Summary: Message Delivery/,/Domain Summary: Messages Received/p'
```

This looks for a line containing `Domain Summary: Message Delivery`, and from that line up until a line containing `Domain Summary: Messages Received` prints out each line.  If it finds another line matching the first, it starts printing again.

The output of the `sed` command is then filtered by `grep` so only lines that contain `yahoo.com` (or `yahooXcom` for any character `X`) are printed.

The `grep` could be omitted:

```
fr_line="Domain Summary: Message Delivery"
to_line="Domain Summary: Messages Received"
sed -n "/$fr_line/,/$to_line/{/yahoo.com/p;}" test_mx1
```

The second example is almost the same; the patterns are different, but otherwise, the command is the same.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` is doing [ranges by patterns](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-29) for a file and then Linux piping `sed`'s output to `grep`. `grep` is printing strings that have `yahoo.com`.